# Embed Woocommerce Product details page info into another page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I simply want to embed my woocommerce product details info into my "Classes" page. I can best explain what I want with images, so am including 3.

1. The Classes page as it is now - http://prnt.sc/c9requ
2. The product details page - http://prnt.sc/c9rfa7

(the rest is in my comment below)

Comment: 3. What I want to Classes page to look like with the product details embed in it -  http://prnt.sc/c9rdza

Here are the urls to the 2 pages. 
Classes page - http://testdrivegolfproducts.com/iw-courses/boxing/
Product details page - http://testdrivegolfproducts.com/product/life-fitness-g7-home-gym/

Comment: Hi Greg, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of posting more information in the comments, you should [edit] your question to include it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch product category from woocommerce by using this code:

```
$args     = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'category' => 34 );
$products = get_posts( $args );
```

Once you have the products, you can loop through and display them using your existing HTML code.